# Can I guarrantee execution of custom finalization code AFTER form destruction?

Tags: delphi, exception, delphi-7, finalization

I have a multithreaded application with many forms, but I have to instantiate some classes and call some initialization stuff before the creation of the forms. 
Of course I have to execute the corresponding finalization code.

Here is a simplified example of .dpr file:

```
begin  // .dpr project file
  LoadDlls;
  try
    Config := TConfig.Create;
    try
      Application.Initialize;
      Application.Title := 'Foo';
      Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
      Application.CreateForm(TOtherForm, OtherForm);
      //...other forms...
      Application.Run;
    finally
      Config.Free;
    end;
  finally
    UnloadDlls;
  end;
end;
```

The problem here is that the code inside `finally` blocks get executed BEFORE the `OnDestroy` / `destructor`s of my forms. 
This turns clear looking at the `finalization` section of `Form` unit:

```
finalization
  if Application <> nil then DoneApplication;
```

And `DoneApplication` calls `Application.DestroyComponents` which effectively Frees all `Application`'s owned Forms.

So, Forms created with `Application.CreateForm` will be destroyed after any code inside the main `begin..end` block.

What I want is that after `Application.Run` all the forms are destroyed, so that their `OnDestroy` event handlers can see the `Config` object and the external functions defined in my dlls. Ditto if an exception is raised. 
But I also want to have the standard Application's exception handling if `Config.Free` or `UnlodDlls` raise (Application must still exist).

Note that:

- I'd prefer not to use a `finalization` block (would it be possible in .dpr?) to keep code clearer and debuggable;
- For now, I prefer not to change too much code (e.g. dynamically create forms)

I think the simplest solution is to explicitly call `Application.DestroyComponents` after `Application.Run`. Do you think is there any drawbacks? 
Is there a more elegant solution?

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The cleanest way to achieve what you want is for you to control the destruction of the forms.

The only form that needs to be owned by `Application` is your main form. That needs to be so because the first form created by a call to `Application.CreateForm` is designated to be the main form. So, my advice is that you should make one call, and one call only to `Application.CreateForm`, to create the main form. For all your other forms, create them by calling their constructors. Let the other forms be owned by the main form. When it's time to shut down, destroy the main form, and let it take all the owned forms with it.

You might write your .dpr code like so:

```
begin 
  LoadDlls;
  try
    Config := TConfig.Create;
    try
      Application.Initialize;
      Application.Title := 'Foo';
      Application.CreateForm(TMainForm, MainForm);
      try
        OtherForm := TOtherForm.Create(MainForm);
        YetAnotherForm := TYetAnotherForm.Create(MainForm);
        Application.Run;
      finally
        FreeAndNil(MainForm); 
        // will destroy the other forms since they are owned by the main form
      end;
    finally
      Config.Free;
    end;
  finally
    UnloadDlls;
  end;
end;
```

One other point to make is that perhaps you don't need to unload the DLLs. Since this is clearly an executable, the system will unload them anyway. Why do you need to do so?

Comment: Thank you, I see your point. I'd like to make this change as a "step 2" because It needs a change in the mind of all members of the team ;-) For now I must guarrantee that if someone adds a form "the standard way" it will be handled correctly. Why not `Application.DestroyComponents`? As for the dlls, you're right, but there are other structures in `LoadDlls` that I want to correctly Free  in order to catch some memory leaks in the main code.

Comment: The system will reclaim the memory at process shutdown. You cannot leak at that point. You are probably safe enough to call `DestroyComponents` at that point. I'd do it properly if I were you, but then I don't know how much influence you have in your team!

Answer (score 4):

Another option is don't let your forms implicitly reference global config.
Make the dependency explicit by giving each form its own reference to an `IConfig` interface.
When the RefCount of the referenced instance drops to zero (after all forms that use it have been destroyed) it can self-destruct.

Making your form's (and other object's) dependency on configuration *explicit* will provide other benefits.

- It will be much easier to test.
- Forms that don't need IConfig won't have the dependency, and won't care eaither way.
- Therefore these forms will be easily (and obviously) moveable into other applications with slightly different framework.

Comment: I'll go deep to this option too, it's very interesting.